# Tell TypeScript compiler that a function alters an argument

Tags: typescript

I have an [Express middlewear](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) function called `checkIsLoggedIn` that validates that a request has a [PassportJs session](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#sessions%00%20%22PassportJS%20Sessions%20documentation) and that that session has a user.  If not, it calls `response.sendStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)`.  If so, it augments `request` with a `user` field set to `request.session.passport.user as MyUser` and calls `next()`.

```ts
import { Request, RequestHandler, Router } from 'express';
import HttpStatus from 'http-status-codes';
import MyUser from './my-user';

interface PassportUser { /* ... */ }

interface ILoggedInRequest extends Request {
    user: MyUser;
    session: {
        passport: {
            user: PassportUser;
        }
    }
}

function transformUser(user: PassportUser): MyUser {
    /* ... */
}

const checkIsLoggedIn: RequestHandler = function (req, res, next) {
    let user: PassportUser | undefined =
        req.session && req.session.passport && req.session.passport.user;
    if (!user) {
        res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        return;
    }

    req.user = transformUser(user);
    next();
}

const router = Router();

router.get('/api/my/route', checkIsLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    // do stuff with req.user
});
```

Is it possible to tell the TypeScript compiler that after `checkIsLoggedIn` is called in the pipeline that `req` at this point implements `ILoggedInRequest`?

Obviously, I could just declare `req: ILoggedInRequest` in my anonymous function...

```ts
router.get('/api/my/route', checkIsLoggedIn, (req: ILoggedInRequest, res) => {
    // do stuff with req.user
});
```

...but I have similar middlewear functions that attach other properties, and I'd rather not declare `req: ILoggedInRequest & ISomeOtherRequest & IAnotherRequest`.  More importantly, I'm still learning TypeScript and am curious if what I'm asking is possible.

I know that creating a type guard could produce this in a more general case...

```ts
function transformArg(myArg: any): myArg is IMyInterface {
    myArg.foo = 'bar';
    return true;
}
```

...though I'm not wild about a type guard having side effects--like *really* not wild; this seems like a horrible idea--so I guess my question boils down to two questions:

1. Can we avoid the type guard misuse? Put another way, can we tell the compiler that calling a function has side effects on its arguments?
2. Can we tell the compiler that...

   ```
   function myFunc(...pipelineFns: (myArg: IBaseInterface) => any): any;
   ```

   ...will call each `pipelineFn` in order, producing those side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that avoids the baggage of a type guard with side-effects is returning "views" of the same object with a different type.

Some thoughts:

```
function transformArg(myArg: Request): IMyInterface | null {
  // ...
}
```

... a function that checks if a request is logged in and returns myArg itself as a `IMyInterface` if so.

I've seen a similar pattern where "weaker" types are returned to protect from mutating an object, e.g.: `function readonly<T>(input: T[]): ReadonlyArray<T> {...}`, but you can do both.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. What do you mean by different views? Essentially these functions should return `void` rather than the argument--otherwise they're not side effects.  And can you give an example of how to use your readonly function?